# Integrating a local php script into drupal block

Tags: blocks

I am trying to integrate a local PHP script (a guestbook script) into a block, but the links it outputs are not correct. They point to the index.php file used from Drupal, instead of point to its own index.php file.

Is there a way to make the links point to the right index file?

Comment: Why not just implement the guestbook in Drupal?

Comment: You mean use the guestbook drupal module, or integrate the actual php script I have into drupal ?

Comment: Either use an existing drupal contrib module, or can make your own content type / fields + View for your own guestbook.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. May you show the code you use to call that script from the block?

Comment: Hello kiamlaluno, and thank you for the welcome message. The code I use to call the script is a simple include and the path to the script. The script is showing in the block, but like I said, the links from the script are pointing to the index file from root.

Comment: If you share at least some of your actual code (or a sanitized/abridged version of it) it will help people answer your question.

Comment: Well the code from the block is like so `<?php include ('path/to/script.php') ?>` and the actual guestbook script is 1341 lines of code. I have discovered the problem and I think it's at this line `<?php echo basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "?action=entry"; ?>` . Now, if I use REQUEST_URI in the scrip itself, drupal gives me an undefined index notice. I must mention that I am not really experienced in drupal nor beginner, or either PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your script is expecting to run index.php from the website root directory which is already used by Drupal.  You will need to re-write the script to use a different root url or set the root url for that script.